# React Native + Appium testing nested accessibility labels

Tags: reactjs, react-native, appium, e2e-testing

I have a couple of custom components in React Native that I'd like access to when doing end-to-end testing with Appium. Some of my components have nested Views, for example (with unnecessary details removed):

**MyView**

```
<View accessibilityLabel={this.props.accessibilityLabel}>
      <TextInput accessibilityLabel={'input'} />
      <Text accessibilityLabel={'error'}>{this.props.error}</Text>
</View>
```

Note how the containing view has its accessibility label set by the parent.

I have a view that contains multiple of the view above, like such:

```
<MyView accessibilityLabel={'email'}/>
<MyView accessibilityLabel={'password'}/>
<MyView accessibilityLabel={'confirmPassword'}/>
```

In Appium, I'd like to access the `TextInput` field of each of the elements separately, like so:

```
const emailInput = await driver.elementByAccessibilityId('email')
     .elementByAccessibilityId('input');
const passwordInput = await driver.elementByAccessibilityId('password')
     .elementByAccessibilityId('input');
```

However, `passwordInput` does not load correctly. Are `accessibilityLabel`s required to be unique? Is nesting them impossible? And how would I solve the problem?

I am aware that I can just include another `prop` to hold the `accessibilityLabel` of `TextInput` within `MyView`, but that seems rather bloated and is not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Instead of adding a new prop, can you not just prepend the existing prop? eg. `<TextInput accessibilityLabel={'${this.props.accessibilityLabel}_input'} />` (those inner apostrophes are supposed to be backticks, but SO won't let me..

Comment: Good point. Nevertheless I'd still like to know if accessibility labels must be unique & if they can be nested.

Comment: I haven't worked with appium in particular, but judging by how you're using the names `await driver.elementByAccessibilityId('email')`, i would imagine that they have to be unique because there would be no other way to know which 'email' field to use.

Comment: Yeah, but see how I'm nesting these calls so the next `elementByAccessibilityId('email')` is called on the `emailInput` instead of `driver` in general. I can't find documentation on how it's intended to act in React Native, but will this allow me to get nested labels?

Comment: solution to this ?